# TreeMap values getting overridden

Tags: java, treemap

I have a treemap which has string as the key and arraylist of integers as the values. I added two values to the treemap. When I add first value to the treemap it was correct. When I add the second value, the values associated with the first key are changed. Both keys are pointing to the same arraylist.

```
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            firstName = resultSet.getString(1);
            lastName = resultSet.getString(2);
            scores.add(Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString(4)));
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String firstName1 = resultSet.getString(1);
                String lastName1 = resultSet.getString(2);
                if (firstName1.equalsIgnoreCase(firstName) && lastName1.equalsIgnoreCase(lastName)) {
                    scores.add(Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString(4)));
                } else {
                    resultSet.previous();
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!studentScores.containsKey(firstName + lastName)) {
                studentScores.put(firstName + lastName, scores);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
                scores.remove(i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the simplest code and the smallest set of source data that demonstrates the problem? For example, remove the database stuff if it doesn't contribute to the problem.

Comment: how about actually debugging it.

Comment: 1) what is the point of `resultSet.previous();` ?  2) Rather than removing all items from your `scores` do `scores = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: I removed part of the code Jason. Sorry about that :) I don't think any of the code can be removed further because everything is involved in changing the treemap :)

Comment: If your keys share the same array list, then the modification of that list will affect both keys.

Comment: One entry would be bypassed when I compare the values. So, I used resultSet.previous if the condition fails @scary

Comment: Do I need to initialize a new array list every time I add it to the treemap ?@ashley

Comment: In that case maybe the second `while` should be an `if`

Comment: `Do I need to initialize a new array list every time I add it to the treemap ?` - seee my comment above

Comment: I reinitialized the ArrayList and its working fine. Thank you Scary Jason and Ashley :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values are getting replaced as you are adding and then removing the same array list for each of the firstName+lastName combination.

Replacing the for loop with `score = new ArrayList();` should fix the issue.